# Manifest file for Sagemaker Processing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've been trying to set up a Sagemaker Processing job using a manifest file, in the Sagemaker python sdk [docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.Processor) it states setting s3_data_type='ManifestFile' would achieve this. However I have tried several formats of manifest file and none seem to work. I'm triggering the processing job using the following code:

```
script_processor = ScriptProcessor(command=['python3'],
                                   image_uri=image_repository_uri,
                                   role=aws_role,
                                   instance_count=instance_count,
                                   instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')

script_processor.run(
    code="my_code.py",
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(
            source=s3_manifest_file_location,
            destination='/opt/ml/processing/input/files',
            s3_data_distribution_type='ShardedByS3Key',
            s3_input_mode='File',
            s3_data_type='ManifestFile'
        )
    ]
)
```

Does anyone have any tips on what format this manifest file should be in or if I'm doing something else wrong? Thanks

Comment: I tried the same thing and it seems ManifestFile cannot be used in Processing jobs. See also [this issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/2578).

Answer (score 0):

An example manifest file is listed in the [S3DataSource docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_S3DataSource.html):

```
[ {"prefix": "s3://customer_bucket/some/prefix/"},

"relative/path/to/custdata-1",

"relative/path/custdata-2",

...

"relative/path/custdata-N"

]
```

Per the docs:

> A manifest is an S3 object which is a JSON file consisting of an array
> of elements. The first element is a prefix which is followed by one or
> more suffixes. SageMaker appends the suffix elements to the prefix to
> get a full set of S3Uri.